# For loop in function printing png files

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to make a for-loop with a function `pathway` that prints a png in the current directory. The `i` is rownames in `paths.hsa.my`. My example below did not yield anything, please see the error below.

```
library("pathview")
for(i  in rownames(paths.hsa.my)){
 pathview(inn.m[,1],pathway.id = "i",species = "hsa")
}
```

head of my input:

```
head(rownames(paths.hsa.my))
[1] "hsa00010" "hsa00020" "hsa00030" "hsa00040" "hsa00051" "hsa00052"
```

Here is my error:

> Warning: Failed to download KEGG xml/png files, hsai skipped!
>
> Info: Downloading xml files for hsai, 1/1 pathways..
>
> Warning: Download of hsai xml file failed!
>       This pathway may not exist!

Comment: add also the adequate packages you're using

Comment: Hard to determine what's going on here without more information, but you should note that the variable `i` in your for-loop is not being used. You were probably looking for something like `pathview(inn.m[,1],pathway.id = paths.hsa.my[i], species    = "hsa")`, although perhaps you also want to include `i` in this term as well `inn.m[,1]`.

Comment: You have quotes around `i` that make it a string, not a variable. Try this:
`for(i  in rownames(paths.hsa.my)){
 pathview(inn.m[,1],pathway.id = i,species = "hsa")
}`